# Errors with simple Neural Network in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a simple neural network. The data is a 231 long vector that is one hot encoded. Each 231 long vectors is assigned an 8 long one hot encoded label.

My code so far is:

```
ssdf = pd.read_csv("/some/path/to/1AMX_one_hot.csv", sep=',')

ss = ssdf.iloc[:,3:11] # slice the df for the ss
labels = ss.values # vector of all ss's
labels = labels.astype('int32')
# data
onehot = ssdf.iloc[:,11:260]
data = onehot.values
data = data.astype('int32')

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Add a softmax layer with 8 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), 
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
          metrics=['accuracy']
)

## fit the model
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

The problem is the output layer is 8 units however my labels are not single units, they are 8-long vectors that are one hot encoded. How do I represent this as an output?

The error message is:

`TypeError: Unable to build 'Dense' layer with non-floating point dtype <dtype: 'int32'>`

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/to/file/main.py", line 36, in <module>
    model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 806, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2503, in     _standardize_user_data
    self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 456, in     _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2773, in     _set_inputs
    outputs = self.call(inputs, training=training)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 256, in call
outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 594, in     __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1713, in     _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 963, in build
    'dtype %s' % (dtype,))
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback. Also in your case you should use categorical cross-entropy loss, not the sparse version.

Comment: Just added traceback! And ah okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your sample code:

1. You need an input layer or input shape for your network.
2. Feed your data **and** labels as: `astype(np.float32)`

If your labels are of shape (150, 8), then fit the last layer with 8 neurons.

```
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**UPDATE:**

```
ssdf = pd.read_csv("/some/path/to/1AMX_one_hot.csv", sep=',')

ss = ssdf.iloc[:,3:11] # slice the df for the ss
labels = ss.values # vector of all ss's
labels = labels.astype('float32')                     # changed this
# data
onehot = ssdf.iloc[:,11:260]
data = onehot.values
data = data.astype('float32')                         # changed this

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

# Add a softmax layer with 8 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), 
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',            # changed this
          metrics=['accuracy']
)

## fit the model
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: The ss[:, 3:11] is already one hot encoded, the output is: 
`[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1] [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]... [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0] [0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]]`

Comment: Then just flatten it (`labels.reshape((labels.shape[0], 64))`) to single dimensional array and enter as `Dense(64, activation='softmax')`.

Comment: I get the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1200 into shape (150,64)`

Comment: What is the shape of your labels array? `print(labels.shape)`

Comment: The shape is (150, 8)

Comment: I understood you wrong then. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: No, don't reshape. I understood your question wrong. :)  Your original error was only the `astype` issue. See update in answer.